# There is an issue with reading tif File format?

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex

I have an image file, in `*.tif` format, that looks like this:
[image]

As you can see it contains an image along with a lot of text. Is there any way to read my `.tif` image and extract the text content into a String ?

Comment: [OCR required?](http://www.investintech.com/resources/articles/extracttext/)

Comment: Apart from OCR is there any JAVA API to read the content on the Image !... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to embed text in a TIFF file using private metadata tags, but it's not usually done. Most likely the text in your image is present only as a picture/bitmap, and the only way to retrieve it is using OCR.

Answer (score 0):

No, the text in the file is not stored as text, it's basically a photo of text. You need to use OCR or some other machine learning method to extract the text from the picture.